# Concurrent collections: Вложенные коллекции

Tags: c#, .net

На сколько потокобезопасна подобная конструкция:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Type1, Dictionary<Type2, Type3>> threadSafeDictionary = new ...
```

Могут быть ситуации, когда несколько потоков модифицируют и читают по определённому ключу вложенный `Dictionary`.

Comment: Небезопасна конечно.

Comment: По-хорошему надо смотреть на ситуацию в целом, но так то конечно если потоки читают-пишут обычный словарь, то это не потокобезопасно, и не важно, в чём этот словарь лежит. Вот если, например, этот словарь (или вообще какой угодно объект) внутри `ConcurrentDictionary` целиком заменяется на другой словарь, без заглядывания в этот объект, просто по ключу - тогда будет потокобезопасно, ведь работа будет только с `ConcurrentDictionary` фактически.

Comment: Используйте мьютекс, если можно: так проще всего и безопаснее всего.

Comment: @CrazyElf Почему так происходит? Ведь по идее `ConcurrentDictionary` не должен позволять нескольким потокам модифицировать объект.

Comment: @D.Stark Он не даёт одновременно модифицировать **ссылку** на объект, которую он хранит, а доступ внутри этого объекта он уже не контролирует.

Comment: @CrazyElf То есть если в словаре хранятся структуры, то несколько потоков могут модифицировать одно поле одновременно?

Comment: @D.Stark Ну, типа того. В общем, потокобезопасность должна быть на всех уровнях. Либо объекты, с которыми вы работаете, должны её сами обеспечивать, либо вы должны это делать за них. Иногда проще обернуть весь блок работы с такими данными в один `lock` и не мучиться. Но такое решение не годиться если доступ к данным очень частый, оно может тормозить и тогда блокировки должны быть более адресными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Несколько потоков модифицируют и читают по определённому ключу вложенный Dictionary

эквивалентно

> Несколько потоков модифицируют и читают один Dictionary

Что небезопасно, и вообще - верный способ поймать дедлок.

Comment: Значит нужно вложенный `Dictionary` заменить на `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: @D.Stark Ну по идее да, хотя хорошо бы посмотреть весь сценарий использования. Потокобезопасность не гарантирует, что у вас в целом всё будет хорошо с логикой работы с данными.